# Joomla site crashes with this PHP code from the Joomla core code

Tags: mysql, joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions

When I'm trying to save content on my joomla site to the database  , it sometimes crashes with these warnings ... This seems to be part of the Joomla core code . It usually saves fine in the database , but it recently started to throw me these errors .. can someone please help me on giving me tips on how I can fix this issue  It's a project I'm working on and I'd like to launch it soon ... It seems to happen when the loading of the site is slow ...

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/content/72/9959172/html/includes/application.php on line 465

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/content/72/9959172/html/libraries/joomla/database/database/mysql.php on line 383

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/content/72/9959172/html/libraries/joomla/database/database/mysql.php on line 383

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/content/72/9959172/html/libraries/joomla/database/table.php on line 406
```

Yesterday it also gave me this error .. It never never used to do what but for some reason when the site loads slow , it will trigger errors .. I'd really appreciate tips on how to fix this . I can't launch a site behaving this way . My host is Godaddy and I used shared hosting.

```
Error loading module MySQL server has gone away SQL=SELECT m.id, m.title, m.module, m.position, m.content, m.showtitle, m.params, mm.menuid FROM pwo3d_modules AS m LEFT JOIN pwo3d_modules_menu AS mm ON mm.moduleid = m.id LEFT JOIN pwo3d_extensions AS e ON e.element = m.module AND e.client_id = m.client_id WHERE m.published = 1 AND e.enabled = 1 AND (m.publish_up = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' OR m.publish_up <= '2013-01-22 04:58:42') AND (m.publish_down = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' OR m.publish_down >= '2013-01-22 04:58:42') AND m.access IN (1,1,2,3) AND m.client_id = 0 AND (mm.menuid = 207 OR mm.menuid <= 0) ORDER BY m.position, m.ordering
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [My Joomla site crashes with this error SQL code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14451959/my-joomla-site-crashes-with-this-error-sql-code)

Comment: I had the same errors you had earlier on on my website, but only lines 2 and 3. I waited 10 minutes and refreshed the page, which solved the problem.

Comment: I know ... but the thing is I wouldn't want the users of my site to experience this .. How can I stop this from happen .. I also refresh and it works .. but this would look ugly for my users . It's a classifieds site I am building with Joomla . The site itself looks good .. what could be triggering this error ?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the server logs, you may be out of memory; if not, download and apply the Joomla update to ensure your files are not corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

In the Godaddy Cpanel page, go down to PHP versions, you can change the PHP version here. The problem with Joomla and Godaddy's PHP version has existed for a long time. It is easy to fix. It takes approximately 20 - 45 mins for changes to be in effect. I changed to 5.5 and it works perfect now.